# "No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack]"

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

After installing X-Pack I get "too many redirections" in the browser and the above message in the Kibana log file.
What went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Restart all 3:
Elasticsearch
Logstash
Kibana

and you're home free.